# Using a sender's name and email address in the header of a PHP email form

Tags: php, email

I can't get the syntax quite right with PHP. How do I change it to display the sender's full name as well as their email address in the 'From:' part this PHP email script?

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$message .= 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . "<br>";
$message .= $_REQUEST['message'];
```

I tried

```
$headers .= "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'] '<'$_REQUEST['name']'>'. "\r\n";
```

But I've screwed up the code somewhere.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Its the other way around, `"From: ". $_REQUEST['name'] . "<". $_REQUEST['email'].">\r\n"`

Comment: You can answer your own question; accept your answer and then close it.

Comment: I suggest using php mail class, like https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Mail headers are `Person Name <email@example.com>` so your header needs to be:

```
$headers .= "From: $_REQUEST[email] <$_REQUEST[name]>\r\n";
```

Comment: Swap email and name fields in your example to match to your answer.